# Cross Service Transactions or Atomicity

Tags: transactions, atomic, distributed-computing, soa, distributed

I have a real-time program that makes a network calls to service A to take a stateful action and network calls to service B to log the history of that action.  The twist is that:

1. We have to revert the action A if B fails (for "reasons," we need a complete history or the action cannot happen at all).  In other words, we cannot write an audit trail unless we have definitely and successfully called the service to take the action (i.e. We can't change the order to call the audit trail first, and then calling the service).
2. There are invalid orderings of the history in B which we cannot have (This is the stateful aspect of A)

There were a few thoughts I had, none which were ideal:

- Get the status of the A before taking the action (which is an available method), and if the call to B fails, we can just call the first service again with the original state.  The problem which is approach is that it's possible that the "revert" call to A will also fail.
- At a high level, this seems to be solveable with "transactions" at a service level (where both service calls both succeed or both fail).  The main algorithm appears to be [2-phase commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol), but it doesn't appear to be something we can use because we don't own the services we're calling so there's no guarantee of stable storage, and we cannot add functionality for it to "agree" with a "transaction coordinator"
- Implement our own best-effort imitation of transactions on our side.  This seems to me to be a fairly complicated approach that would be difficult or impossible to get right
- Have an ability to get into an "eventually consistent state."  However, as per 2, some orderings are not possible so we would have to wait for all the queued actions to make it before continuing.  This would make our service potentially not real-time anyore

Is there any solution in which we can have the complete mirror of the logs satisfying the requirements with 100% correctness?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the protocol that all your services are communicating on, for the sake of this answer I'm assuming HTTP.

Like you said non of your possible solutions sound like they would work for you.

1. Its far too easy for services to change state before or after a status check and like you said any remedial action afterwards can also easily fail.
2. I think in the scenario you have outlined a 2 phase commit is out of the question. even if you did own all the services its difficult to get this right using just HTTP.
3. I agree
4. Of all the options this one has legs. It all depends on your requirements for 'real time'. Whenever someone says this i ask 'what do you mean?' nothing is 'real time' everything takes some time to process. There is always a period of time from someone, or something asking for something to be done to it actually getting done! the difference between milliseconds seconds and minutes is just a matter or requirements and how much money you have to throw around.

So you say that a call to your service (lets call it X) over HTTP calls the two services A and B sincronously again both over HTTP. If you have many calls to X at the same time there is no way (or at least its very hard) to ensure the ordering of calls to A result in the same order of calls to B. But this again depends on your requirements and what the system is doing and how, maybe there is only one call to your system every day?

Personally I would recommend the use of queues, and to move towards an event driven architecture. Even with an eventually consistent system you can have it running hot and get the 'real time' that you desire, it will just cost you more!

I hope this has been useful to you. I'm very interested to hear your thoughts regarding my suggestions.

Comment: I think minutes is an acceptable time to wait, and traffic is not expected to be too high.  Though I think there would be significant effort to develop a solution to have a durable local queue.

Comment: There is so much technology to help you in this area, you would not be developing a new solution to this. Just look at all the tech available on todays cloud providers. We make heavy use of sqs in AWS and if your on prem you can use kafka, zeroMQ or rabbitMQ so many options. developing an event driven system is easier than you think.